# Imagick fails to enable on Ubuntu with php-fpm and nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm, imagemagick

Alright, I've followed numerous guides trying to get Imagick PECL extension working on my machine but no matter what I do, `phpinfo()` or `extension_loaded('imagick')` doesn't detect it.

If I run `php5-fpm -m`, imagick **does** show up in the list, which means it should be working, right?

If I add `extension=imagick.so` to my php.ini, I only get an error that it's already been loaded.

- `/var/log/php5-fpm.log` shows nothing relevant
- `/var/log/php_error.log` gives `PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0` after I restart the service.

Versions:

- php5-imagick: 3.1.2-1build1
- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (fpm-fcgi)
- nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Please include the software versions.

Comment: Gotcha, Done @Paul

Comment: Okay, I haven't used the imagick PECL, but the [Description](https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) states: "Imagick is a native php extension to create and modify images using the ImageMagick API.  This extension requires ImageMagick version 6.2.4+ and PHP 5.1.3+." Do you have ImageMagick version 6.2.4+ installed?